# angularjs call a service injecting in the parent in the children

Tags: angularjs

I'm finding a way to call a service
injecting in the parent from within a children.

I ended up with

```
<div ng-controller="ParentController">
        <div ng-controller="ChildController">{{my}}</div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.factory('Data',function(){
        return {show:function(msg){return msg;}};
     });
    app.controller('ParentController',function($scope,Data){
        $scope.shareService = Data;

     });
     app.controller('ChildController',function($scope){
        $scope.my = $scope.$parent.shareService.show('Hey');
     });
    </script>
```

I'm wondering if could be a good practice (may be it's not very handy) or not
or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If the service is independent of the parent controller, you can inject the service directly in the child controller like you did in parent controller. Why create a dependency on the parent scope.

Services by definition are meant to be shared across controllers, directive and other services.

Comment: The service is a sort navigation title like .factory('WindowUtils', function($window,CONFIG) {
        return {
           setTitle:function(str){
               var title= '';
               var base = CONFIG.site.title;
               if(typeof str === 'undefined'){
                   title = base;
               }
               else{
                   title = base + CONFIG.site.separator + str;
               }
               $window.document.title = title;
           }
        }
    }) so I would use it without injecting in all children

Comment: If you define it over a controller all controllers defined on child html would have access to the service so you cannot control that. One of the reasons to use services is to make dependencies explicit.

Comment: because of .controller('ContestantProductCtrl',function($scope,$location,WindowUtils) {
        WindowUtils.setTitle('Scegli il tuo miele');
     })
    .controller('ContestantCreateCtrl',function($scope,$location,WindowUtils) {
        WindowUtils.setTitle('Partecipa');
    }) I should set it directly in all controller